# Audio Files downloaded from YouTube-DL are corrupted

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I have written a small piece of code that downloads audios and videos from YouTube using `YouTube-DL`. Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

link = input("Enter the video link:")

while True:
    choice = input("Enter a for audio file, v for video file:")
    if choice == "a" or choice == "v":
        break

ydl_opts = {}

if choice == "a":
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }
else:
    ydl_opts = {'format':137}
    
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    info_dict = ydl.extract_info(link, download=False)
    video_title = info_dict.get('title', None)

if choice == "a":
    path = f'D:\\DwnldsYT\\{video_title}.mp3'
if choice == "v":
    path = f'D:\\DwnldsYT\\{video_title}.mp4'

ydl_opts.update({'outtmpl':path})

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([link])
```

This works fine. I am able to play the downloaded audio. But when I try to read the same audio file, it shows me an error.

Code:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

song = AudioSegment.from_mp3("D:\\DwnldsYT\\Cartoon - On & On (feat. Daniel Levi) [NCS Release].mp3")
```

Output:

```
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3float @ 000001f2425c2500] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[abuffer @ 000001f242280300] Value inf for parameter 'time_base' out of range [0 - 2.14748e+09]
    Last message repeated 3 times
[abuffer @ 000001f242280300] Error setting option time_base to value 1/0.
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 000001f242280e80] Error applying options to the filter.
Error reinitializing filters!
Error while filtering: Result too large
Finishing stream 0:0 without any data written to it.
[abuffer @ 000001f242280300] Value inf for parameter 'time_base' out of range [0 - 2.14748e+09]
    Last message repeated 3 times
[abuffer @ 000001f242280300] Error setting option time_base to value 1/0.
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 000001f242280e80] Error applying options to the filter.
Error configuring filter graph
Conversion failed!
```

Is this because the audio downloaded is corrupted? And how to solve this problem? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could it be the case that although file has `.mp3` extension it might be encoded as `.aac` format (AAC codec)? Which is the default format for `.mp4` and AVC video codec.

Comment: Try doing `ffmpeg -i filename.mp3` and see, for MP3 it should output something like `Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s`.

Comment: Try just doing `AudioSegment.from_file(path)` instead of `AudioSegment.from_mp3(path)`.

Comment: Yeah...```AudioSegment.from_file(path)``` works. But then, if I upload the downloaded audio file in a website, the website isn't able to process the audio file properly.

Comment: For example, this is the website where I wanted to upload my audio file -- https://audioalter.com/8d-audio/ If I upload my audio file to this website, it isn't converting it to 8d.

Comment: Convert it to `wav` format before uploading, don't convert it to MP3, otherwise you lose original quality. WAV is lossless format. Conversion is simple, using [FFMpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) tool - `ffmpeg -i filename.aac filename.wav`.

Comment: I see this site has limit of `20MB`, hence you need compressed lossless format, like FLAC, because WAV is uncompressed, so do `ffmpeg -i filename.aac filename.flac`.

Comment: I've updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64085621/941531) to include commands/tips regarding lossless formats conversion and 8D processing.

Comment: Ok...Thx a tonne!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your audio file is probably encoded not as MP3. It is probably [AAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Audio_Coding) (usually having file extension `.aac`), which is the default format for `.mp4` and AVC video codec and youtube.

Instead of `AudioSegment.from_mp3(path)` try doing `AudioSegment.from_file(path)` it will detect format by itself or `AudioSegment.from_file(path, format = 'aac')` to force it to decode AAC.

Also you can detect format by using [FFMpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) by running `ffmpeg -i filename.mp3`, for MP3 it should output something like `Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s`, and for other formats it will be non-`mp3` string.

Probably `youtube-dl` library has some options to always force re-encoding to MP3, if you really need only MP3, although beware that you will lose some quality by re-conversion. Right now your options contain `preferred` word for MP3, it means that it prefers MP3 downloading, but doesn't force this output format.

If it doesn't matter for you if it is MP3 or AAC, then stay with original youtube's format, you will keep best quality then, you may also rename files with `.aac` extension for clarity.

If you want Youtube-downloaded files to be processed later e.g. by [8D Audio Site](https://audioalter.com/8d-audio/), then not to lose quality when processing you need to convert your file to some lossless format like WAV. You can do this using [FFMpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) tool, like this `ffmpeg -i filename.aac filename.wav`.

Also [8D Audio Site](https://audioalter.com/8d-audio/) has `20MB` file size limit, hence you may need to split your WAV file. In order to split into parts of 30 seconds each you need to run `ffmpeg -i filename.wav -f segment -segment_time 30 -c copy "filename%03d.wav"` and then upload and process each part. You can concatenate processed WAVs afterwards using [sox](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/files/sox/14.4.2/) as `sox sound0*.wav soundall.wav`. And convert to some compressed but lossless format like [FLAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAC) as `ffmpeg -i soundall.wav soundall.flac`.

All conversion/splitting/merging commands can be easilty automated using Python's standard module [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). E.g. to run any command like `ffmpeg -i sound.mp3 sound.wav` you have just to do in Python one line `subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', 'sound.mp3', 'sound.wav'], check = True)`.

All professionals are editing and storing audio files in some lossless format like WAV or FLAC, not to lose quality on each stage of processing, so it is a good practice, especially if you want to 8D-process file definitely MP3 reconversion several times will be a bad idea.

If [this library](https://github.com/dakshj48/8D-Audio-Converter/blob/master/audioCon.py#L9) does 8D conversion mathematically correctly then my next code will do correct WAV conversion, it is just a minimal working sub-code of that library for WAV only.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64085443#main.py)

```py
# Needs: python -m pip install pydub numpy

def ConvertTo8D(input_file_name, output_file_name, *, period = 200):
    import numpy as np
    from pydub import AudioSegment
    
    if period < 0:
        period = -period
    elif period == 0:
        period = 200
        
    audio = AudioSegment.from_file(input_file_name)
    audio = audio + AudioSegment.silent(duration = 150)
    
    eightD = AudioSegment.empty()
    pan = 0.9 * np.sin(np.linspace(0, 2. * np.pi, period))

    for i, chunk in enumerate(audio[::100]):
        if len(chunk) < 100:
            continue
        newChunk = chunk.pan(pan[i % period])
        eightD = eightD + newChunk

    eightD.export(output_file_name, format = output_file_name[output_file_name.rfind('.') + 1:])

# Test Usage
ConvertTo8D('sound.wav', 'sound-8D.wav')
```

Comment: Thx! A small query. Shall I change ```preferred``` to ```wav``` so that ```youtube-dl``` downloads the audio as a ```wav``` file?

Comment: But the file size is way too huge when I download the audio as ```wav```. The file size of the audio of https://youtu.be/Hn4sfC2PbhI is almost 40mb.

Comment: @Sushil By `preferred` this library probably means next behavior - it queries Youtube for all available formats of video/audio streams, then if it finds `preferred` format of audio among original stream formats then it downloads this preferred, otherwise it downloads some closest to preferred format. Hence it doesn't mean that downloaded format will be exactly as that specified by preferred. It just tries to find closest downloadable format but without reconversion.

Comment: Ok...But wht abt the file size?

Comment: @Sushil You're saying WAV is too big. It is not a big problem, because I changed my answer to include commands of cutting into 30-seconds or more parts, use that command. If you want 8D processing, definitely you should download original WAV and cut it.

Comment: @Sushil I don't know if YouTube really stores WAV on their servers, maybe Youtube-DL library just converts downloaded AAC to WAV. But still better to specify options to download WAV if it is avaialable for some reason on Google. Otherwise you need to convert AAC to WAV. Also is is very important to download using library the highest available bitrate, there should be such option. All these is needed if you want really superb 8D audio.

Comment: @Sushil I think the whole pipeline (down/convert/split/upload/process/download/join/convert) can be not-so-difficultly coded/automated using Python. 8D-Audio Site should have some public API for uploading/downloading. Even if it is not, still it is possible just by emulating website's upload process, you just need to look into HTML/JavaScript source of that website.

Comment: Ok...Will try to do it. Or instead, I will try to write a python code that converts a normal audio file (how much ever big it is) into an 8d audio file.

Comment: @Sushil I see there exist different libraries for 8D conversion [like this one](https://github.com/maxgillham/8D-Audio).

Comment: @Sushil BTW, I see it takes just several lines of mathematical processing of audio in Python to make it 8D, [see lines here](https://github.com/dakshj48/8D-Audio-Converter/blob/master/audioCon.py#L18).

Comment: Ok...Can u pls help me with calling the function? Cuz I haven't worked with ```ArgumentParsers``` so far.

Comment: @Sushil In fact Argument parsing is not needed at all, it is just there to accept input and output file names on command line. You may just copy conversion piece of code [which is here](https://github.com/dakshj48/8D-Audio-Converter/blob/master/audioCon.py#L18), just dozen of lines. And provide input/output file names the way you like.

Comment: @Sushil I'll write full shortest script now, will be easy.

Comment: Looks like this code doesn't support ```wav``` files.

Comment: Plus, it doesn't give a proper 8D effect :(

Comment: @Sushil If that library is correct in doing 8D math then [my next code](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64085443#main.py) should work, it is minimal sub-code of that library needed to convert WAV. Try it online! It needs only two python packages `python -m pip install pydub numpy`.

Comment: This works fine. But it doesn't give the effect that I get when I use that website. The only problem is that sometimes the loudness is too low in one ear and too high in another that it causes ear pain. I had another 8D code and it had the same prob. I couldn't figure out why it is so. Anyways, thx!